# Transforming \" into " using Haskell / Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm going through [Write Yourself A Scheme](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours) tutorial and there's a exercise which I can't solve.

> Our strings aren't quite R5RS compliant, because they don't support escaping of internal quotes within the string. Change `parseString` so that \" gives a literal quote character instead of terminating the string. You may want to replace `noneOf "\""` with a new parser action that accepts either a non-quote character or a backslash followed by a quote mark.

The actual ParseString code function is:

```
parseString :: Parser LispVal
parseString = do
        char '"'
        x <- many (noneOf "\"")
        char '"'
        return $ String x
```

I've tried in many ways to do it. My attempted solution was:

```
parseString :: Parser LispVal
parseString = do
        char '"'
        x <- many (satisfy (/= '"') <|> (string "\"" >> return '"'))
        char '"'
        return $ String x
```

My rationale is that `(string "\"" >> return '"')` will consume a string formed \" and return a single double-quote character, but it's not working as expected. I also researched over the internet but didn't found a solution.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but I recommend factoring out the stuff inside `many` into a separate (possibly non-exported) function. Your `parseString` is looking a bit monolithic there, and that'd be a pretty good place to modularize it a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll do it for sure

Comment: As a small syntactic improvement, instead of `string "\\\"" >> return '"'` you should be able to write `'"' <$ string "\\\""`. The `(<$) :: a -> f b -> f a` operator runs the functor on the right and evaluates to the value on the left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing `"\""` in Haskell produces a string with a single element. That's because the Haskell parser is consuming the backslash and it never gets to your program. You need to double escape it, so that both Haskell and your parser are satisfied.

```
noneOf "\"\\" <|> (string "\\\"" >> return '"')
```

Comment: Why use `anyChar` at all? If you use `noneOf "\"\\"`, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Fair point. Edited. The only possible problem is that this won't (currently) parse backslash at all if not followed by a quote. But I imagine the OP is fixing to add other backslash escape-sequences, so that's the way we probably want it to look anyway. Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks for the great answer